# Proving $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$ is path-connected

Tags: general-topology

To show that any interval in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is path-connected, we can create a function, such as $f(t) = (1-t)a + tb$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$, that is continuous, and maps $[0,1]$ to any interval in $\mathbb{R}^1$. This shows that any interval in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is path-connected.

Now, to show that a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is path-connected, or to show that a region in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is path-connected, would I follow a similar approach, of creating a continuous function that maps $[0,1]$ to some region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or $\mathbb{R}^3$)? Or is there a better approach to thinking about this question?

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^n$ is path-connected because the line $f(t) = (1-t)a + tb$ for $t \in [0,1]$ joins any two points $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The formula for line segments in $\mathbb R^n$ is pretty much exactly the same as for in $\mathbb R$, the only difference being that you use vector operations in $\mathbb R^n$ (vector addition, scalar multiplication) instead of real number operations in $\mathbb R$ (real addition, real multiplication).

Comment: Or you could show connectedness implies path connectedness in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: The title of the question is not what your actual question is, and you don't have to distinguish $\mathbb R^2$ from $\mathbb R^3$. For *any* $n$, you show that a *region* in $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected by creating that continuous function. However : rather than me giving you that exact formulation please reproduce it yourself. ***Hint*** . You need to start with two arbitrary points in your given region. You cannot throw around with words like "a region" and then "some region" . It is so basic.